# On adding new items in listview, I want a checkbox with it

Tags: android, android-studio

On adding new item in the list view, I want a checkbox on left side of it. I have tried a lot but I am not getting the exact result. Here is the code:

```
 ListView list;
    Button btn, btn1, btn2, btn3;
    EditText edt;
    CheckBox chk;
    TextView txt;
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    String[] ListElements = new String[]{
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //find view by ids
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt);
        chk = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        final List<String> txt = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(ListElements));

        ArrayList<CheckBox> boxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, txt);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        //final ListView listView = getListView();

        list.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txt.add(edt.getText().toString());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently you are using a default ArrayAdapter for your list view. Try using a custom adapter - this will allow you to customise your list view layout and add a check box on the left.

Here is an [example](https://www.raywenderlich.com/124438/android-listview-tutorial).

Or, something like this:

1. Create `layout` for `ListView` row:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
               android:padding="10dp">

       <CheckBox
           android:id="@+id/check_box"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/text_view"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:text="Dummy Text"
           android:textAllCaps="true"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. Create model class for `ListView` row:

   ```
   public class CheckItem {

       private String name;
       private boolean isChecked;

       public CheckItem(String name, boolean isChecked) {
           this.name = name;
           this.isChecked = isChecked;
       }

       public String getName() {
           return name;
       }

       public boolean isChecked() {
           return isChecked;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create the `adapter` for the `ListView`:

   ```
   public class CheckItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CheckItem> {

       private List<CheckItem> dataSet;

       public CheckItemAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<CheckItem> dataSet) {
           super(context, resource);
           this.dataSet = dataSet;
       }

       @Override 
       public int getCount() {
           return dataSet.size();
       }

       @Override 
       public CheckItem getItem(int position) {
           return dataSet.get(position);
       }

       @Override 
       public long getItemId(int position) {
           return position;
       }

       @Override 
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

           ViewHolder holder;

           if (convertView == null) {

               // Inflate layout
               convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                   .inflate(R.layout.adapter, parent, false);

               // Setup ViewHolder
               holder = new ViewHolder();
               holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_box);
               holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);

               // Store ViewHolder with this row view
               convertView.setTag(holder);

           } else {

               // Use viewHolder - quicker than calling findViewById() on resource every time
               holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
           }

           // Get item from your data set at the current list position
           CheckItem checkItem = getItem(position);

           if (checkItem != null) {
               // Set the views to match the item from your data set
               holder.checkBox.setChecked(checkItem.isChecked());
               holder.textView.setText(checkItem.getName());
            }

            return convertView;
       }

       // ViewHolder acts as a cache for row views
       private class ViewHolder {
           TextView textView;
           CheckBox checkBox;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Set `adapter` to `ListView` in your `Activity`:

   ```
   @Override 
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_layout);

       ...

       List<CheckItem> checkItems = new ArrayList<>();

       // Provide adapter with dummy data for testing
       for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
           checkItems.add(new CheckItem("Check Item " + (i + 1), i % 2 == 0));
       }

       CheckItemAdapter adapter = new CheckItemAdapter(this, R.layout.adapter, checkItems);
       ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

       listView.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
   ```

Comment: Yeah sure. Did you look at the example?

Comment: yeah, but i am not getting it

Comment: Ok, no problem. The first thing you need to do is make a layout file for a row in your list view. Based on your question, this will need to have a `CheckBox` to the left and a `TextView`. Have you done this?

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"         android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/chk"
    android:focusable="false"/>
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:id="@+id/txt"/>
    
</LinearLayout>

Comment: Ok, is that the layout you want? You can check it in the preview bar on the right (presuming you are using Android Studio).

Comment: The next thing to do is make a model class for your list items. This will be used to populate each row of your ListView. Based on your question I would suggest something like a CheckItem (you can call it what you want).

Comment: The `model` will need to have `class variables` that can be used to populate each row. So a `boolean` for the `CheckBox` and a `String` for the `TextView`.

Comment: I just realised you do not have enough reputation to move this discussion to a chat, so I have updated my answer to provide an example. You can customise it to your needs. Hope this helps.